# Why my java young gc time take longer and longer?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I hava a proxy server project, it deal about 60,000 request per minute. I found the gc time is wired. The young gc time takes longer and longer.

My gc log

```
2015-05-16T07:58:25.660+0800: 359.833: [GC2015-05-16T07:58:25.660+0800: 359.833: [ParNew: 11426343K->459256K(13165760K), 0.1861630 secs] 11426343K->459256K(18285760K), 0.1864010 secs] [Times: user=1.77 sys=0.01, real=0.18 secs] 
2015-05-16T07:59:23.398+0800: 417.571: [GC2015-05-16T07:59:23.398+0800: 417.571: [ParNew: 11430776K->509760K(13165760K), 0.2254760 secs] 11430776K->509760K(18285760K), 0.2257140 secs] [Times: user=2.16 sys=0.01, real=0.22 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:00:14.522+0800: 468.695: [GC2015-05-16T08:00:14.522+0800: 468.695: [ParNew: 11481280K->445475K(13165760K), 0.1242330 secs] 11481280K->445475K(18285760K), 0.1245000 secs] [Times: user=1.14 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:01:04.571+0800: 518.745: [GC2015-05-16T08:01:04.571+0800: 518.745: [ParNew: 11416995K->503881K(13165760K), 0.1334070 secs] 11416995K->503881K(18285760K), 0.1336370 secs] [Times: user=1.24 sys=0.01, real=0.13 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:01:55.006+0800: 569.179: [GC2015-05-16T08:01:55.006+0800: 569.180: [ParNew: 11475401K->483236K(13165760K), 0.1277270 secs] 11475401K->483236K(18285760K), 0.1279680 secs] [Times: user=1.18 sys=0.01, real=0.13 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:02:53.500+0800: 627.673: [GC2015-05-16T08:02:53.500+0800: 627.673: [ParNew: 11454756K->567960K(13165760K), 0.1926360 secs] 11454756K->567960K(18285760K), 0.1928680 secs] [Times: user=1.84 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:03:52.168+0800: 686.342: [GC2015-05-16T08:03:52.168+0800: 686.342: [ParNew: 11539480K->508020K(13165760K), 0.2197430 secs] 11539480K->508020K(18285760K), 0.2199800 secs] [Times: user=2.10 sys=0.00, real=0.22 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:04:47.986+0800: 742.159: [GC2015-05-16T08:04:47.986+0800: 742.159: [ParNew: 11479540K->483623K(13165760K), 0.2012450 secs] 11479540K->483623K(18285760K), 0.2014780 secs] [Times: user=1.90 sys=0.01, real=0.20 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:05:43.425+0800: 797.598: [GC2015-05-16T08:05:43.425+0800: 797.598: [ParNew: 11455143K->499526K(13165760K), 0.2690110 secs] 11455143K->539947K(18285760K), 0.2692350 secs] [Times: user=2.42 sys=0.03, real=0.27 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:06:42.983+0800: 857.156: [GC2015-05-16T08:06:42.983+0800: 857.156: [ParNew: 11471046K->478080K(13165760K), 0.3499460 secs] 11511467K->585893K(18285760K), 0.3501800 secs] [Times: user=3.29 sys=0.00, real=0.35 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:07:43.872+0800: 918.045: [GC2015-05-16T08:07:43.872+0800: 918.045: [ParNew: 11449600K->464130K(13165760K), 0.3170180 secs] 11557413K->574042K(18285760K), 0.3172810 secs] [Times: user=3.09 sys=0.00, real=0.32 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:08:39.809+0800: 973.983: [GC2015-05-16T08:08:39.809+0800: 973.983: [ParNew: 11435650K->450610K(13165760K), 0.3563240 secs] 11545562K->562538K(18285760K), 0.3565520 secs] [Times: user=3.45 sys=0.01, real=0.36 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:09:36.247+0800: 1030.420: [GC2015-05-16T08:09:36.247+0800: 1030.420: [ParNew: 11422130K->475736K(13165760K), 0.3948640 secs] 11534058K->594208K(18285760K), 0.3951130 secs] [Times: user=3.86 sys=0.00, real=0.40 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:10:28.126+0800: 1082.299: [GC2015-05-16T08:10:28.126+0800: 1082.299: [ParNew: 11447256K->539808K(13165760K), 0.4354400 secs] 11565728K->662084K(18285760K), 0.4357260 secs] [Times: user=4.24 sys=0.01, real=0.44 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:11:18.431+0800: 1132.604: [GC2015-05-16T08:11:18.431+0800: 1132.605: [ParNew: 11511328K->506115K(13165760K), 0.4649390 secs] 11633604K->632306K(18285760K), 0.4651880 secs] [Times: user=4.55 sys=0.01, real=0.47 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:12:11.087+0800: 1185.261: [GC2015-05-16T08:12:11.087+0800: 1185.261: [ParNew: 11477635K->597355K(13165760K), 0.5022610 secs] 11603826K->727427K(18285760K), 0.5025890 secs] [Times: user=4.92 sys=0.00, real=0.50 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:13:08.187+0800: 1242.360: [GC2015-05-16T08:13:08.187+0800: 1242.360: [ParNew: 11568875K->482715K(13165760K), 0.5356720 secs] 11698947K->617514K(18285760K), 0.5359150 secs] [Times: user=5.26 sys=0.00, real=0.54 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:14:06.023+0800: 1300.196: [GC2015-05-16T08:14:06.023+0800: 1300.196: [ParNew: 11454235K->477157K(13165760K), 0.5269100 secs] 11589034K->632904K(18285760K), 0.5271740 secs] [Times: user=5.13 sys=0.01, real=0.53 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:15:01.303+0800: 1355.477: [GC2015-05-16T08:15:01.303+0800: 1355.477: [ParNew: 11448677K->655192K(13165760K), 0.6135160 secs] 11604424K->822286K(18285760K), 0.6138640 secs] [Times: user=6.02 sys=0.00, real=0.61 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:15:53.316+0800: 1407.489: [GC2015-05-16T08:15:53.316+0800: 1407.489: [ParNew: 11626712K->505502K(13165760K), 0.6275970 secs] 11793806K->683727K(18285760K), 0.6278620 secs] [Times: user=6.18 sys=0.00, real=0.63 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:16:37.701+0800: 1451.874: [GC2015-05-16T08:16:37.701+0800: 1451.874: [ParNew: 11477022K->493920K(13165760K), 0.1365010 secs] 11655247K->676600K(18285760K), 0.1367440 secs] [Times: user=1.28 sys=0.01, real=0.14 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:17:28.338+0800: 1502.511: [GC2015-05-16T08:17:28.338+0800: 1502.511: [ParNew: 11465440K->485473K(13165760K), 0.1307090 secs] 11648120K->672195K(18285760K), 0.1309590 secs] [Times: user=1.20 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:18:22.343+0800: 1556.516: [GC2015-05-16T08:18:22.343+0800: 1556.516: [ParNew: 11456993K->412544K(13165760K), 0.1325270 secs] 11643715K->603596K(18285760K), 0.1327730 secs] [Times: user=1.23 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:19:19.744+0800: 1613.917: [GC2015-05-16T08:19:19.744+0800: 1613.917: [ParNew: 11384064K->538411K(13165760K), 0.1575330 secs] 11575116K->733767K(18285760K), 0.1578060 secs] [Times: user=1.47 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:20:13.689+0800: 1667.863: [GC2015-05-16T08:20:13.689+0800: 1667.863: [ParNew: 11509931K->467140K(13165760K), 0.1500950 secs] 11705287K->666590K(18285760K), 0.1503770 secs] [Times: user=1.38 sys=0.01, real=0.15 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:21:03.746+0800: 1717.919: [GC2015-05-16T08:21:03.746+0800: 1717.919: [ParNew: 11438660K->491515K(13165760K), 0.1573820 secs] 11638110K->695292K(18285760K), 0.1576390 secs] [Times: user=1.47 sys=0.01, real=0.16 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:21:57.057+0800: 1771.231: [GC2015-05-16T08:21:57.057+0800: 1771.231: [ParNew: 11463035K->494812K(13165760K), 0.1683290 secs] 11666812K->703187K(18285760K), 0.1685830 secs] [Times: user=1.58 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:22:53.009+0800: 1827.183: [GC2015-05-16T08:22:53.009+0800: 1827.183: [ParNew: 11466332K->503009K(13165760K), 0.2752990 secs] 11674707K->715630K(18285760K), 0.2755490 secs] [Times: user=2.65 sys=0.01, real=0.28 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:23:49.248+0800: 1883.421: [GC2015-05-16T08:23:49.248+0800: 1883.421: [ParNew: 11474529K->592507K(13165760K), 0.3214050 secs] 11687150K->810982K(18285760K), 0.3216520 secs] [Times: user=3.10 sys=0.02, real=0.32 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:24:45.261+0800: 1939.434: [GC2015-05-16T08:24:45.261+0800: 1939.434: [ParNew: 11564027K->524559K(13165760K), 0.2616300 secs] 11782502K->747578K(18285760K), 0.2618880 secs] [Times: user=2.49 sys=0.02, real=0.26 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:25:41.077+0800: 1995.250: [GC2015-05-16T08:25:41.077+0800: 1995.250: [ParNew: 11496079K->614392K(13165760K), 0.3724070 secs] 11719098K->842089K(18285760K), 0.3726700 secs] [Times: user=3.61 sys=0.01, real=0.37 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:26:37.097+0800: 2051.271: [GC2015-05-16T08:26:37.097+0800: 2051.271: [ParNew: 11585912K->581647K(13165760K), 0.4181700 secs] 11813609K->813745K(18285760K), 0.4184100 secs] [Times: user=4.08 sys=0.00, real=0.42 secs] 
2015-05-16T08:27:30.132+0800: 2104.305: [GC2015-05-16T08:27:30.132+0800: 2104.305: [ParNew: 11553167K->524464K(13165760K), 0.4743670 secs] 11785265K->761376K(18285760K), 0.4746240 secs] [Times: user=4.66 sys=0.00, real=0.48 secs]
```

sometimes it reach 600 ms, then back to 150 ms. And then grow longer and longer again.

My heap info:

```
Attaching to process ID 33415, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.45-b08

using parallel threads in the new generation.
using thread-local object allocation.
Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 20971520000 (20000.0MB)
   NewSize          = 15728640000 (15000.0MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 15728640000 (15000.0MB)
   OldSize          = 5242880000 (5000.0MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 5
   PermSize         = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 13481738240 (12857.1875MB)
   used     = 7330310008 (6990.728385925293MB)
   free     = 6151428232 (5866.459114074707MB)
   54.37214309836652% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 11234836480 (10714.375MB)
   used     = 6871073864 (6552.766670227051MB)
   free     = 4363762616 (4161.608329772949MB)
   61.15864593340303% used
From Space:
   capacity = 2246901760 (2142.8125MB)
   used     = 459236144 (437.9617156982422MB)
   free     = 1787665616 (1704.8507843017578MB)
   20.438639204234725% used
To Space:
   capacity = 2246901760 (2142.8125MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 2246901760 (2142.8125MB)
   0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 5242880000 (5000.0MB)
   used     = 334762784 (319.2546691894531MB)
   free     = 4908117216 (4680.745330810547MB)
   6.385093383789062% used
Perm Generation:
   capacity = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   used     = 60901216 (58.079925537109375MB)
   free     = 207534240 (197.92007446289062MB)
   22.68747091293335% used

30149 interned Strings occupying 3285592 bytes.
```

My jvm configuration

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=11000m -Xms20000m -Xmx20000m -XX:NewSize=15000m -XX:SurvivorRatio=5 -XX:PermSize=256m -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dqunar.logs=$CATALINA_BASE/logs -Dqunar.cache=$CATALINA_BASE/cache -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:$CATALINA_BASE/logs/gc.log
```

I want to know why the time of young gc will grow longer and longer

How can I reduce it?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know why the time of young gc will grow longer and longer

There could be a number of causes, but I think that the most likely ones are:

- You have a memory leak, and the increased young gc times are caused by the buildup of leaked objects.
- You are caching a lot of "stuff" in memory, and this is affecting GC times.  (The drops in the time could correlate with the GC deciding that it needs to break weak links in your cache data structure to reduce memory pressure.)

In both cases, it is worth noting that GC times are more dependent on the number of live objects than the amount of garbage that you have.  Anything that causes the number of live objects to trend upwards is going to increase GC times.

> How can I reduce it?

First identify the cause of the increases in time.  Make sure it isn't due to something your application is doing.

Then read the advice here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-tame-java-gc-pauses.  Keeping pause times under control with a large heap (20Gb is large) is not easy.

Reviewing the options you have set, I suspect that `-XX:NewSize=15000m` could be part of the problem.  It is *forcing* the young space to be very large - 3/4 of your total heap size.  Since the CMS minor collections are stop-the-world, this is going to directly impact on pause times.  Maybe it will do better if you remove that option or set it to something smaller.

**UPDATE**

And apparently, reducing the size of the young space *does* reduce pause times.

Comment: CMS will stop the world while the young gc, so I think 500 ms is a long time. And I think I should dump the heap to analyze the largest live objects. But it's a production environment system ...

Comment: You are right.  You can reduce the minor GC times by reducing the size of the young generation.

Comment: `MaxGCPauseMillis` does not affect CMS, it is a flag for `G1`

Comment: You have 15GB young generation which is stop-the-world collected. Try reducing it by an odred of magnitude

Comment: I am new to jvm, why CMS will stop the world while *young* gc?

Comment: @Hanfeng - Because it does.  Ask the designers.  (Possibly because not stopping the world results in much lower throughput because collection of the young generation takes more time, memory barrier costs increase, etc)